# How do I load a page by clicking a link in Asual Jquery tabs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I'm using Asuals JQuery tab plugin and I want to be able to load a page by clicking a link that is found within the tab content. But the plugin doesn't seem to want to load my link via ajax, it just loads like a regular link.

So how do I load a page via ajax by clicking a link in a Asual Jquery tab?

Comment: @tjameson No it's local. I'm trying to load viewtopic.php from the tab forum.php

Comment: It's just a little hard to diagnose without something to look at, hence the live page request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using another plugin that in my opinion was more beginner friendly. It's called [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/).